# JavaFx TableView - how to style rows on startup based on data?

Tags: java, javafx

Need some help. I'm doing a proof of concept project that I may end up applying to a much larger project.

On this project I have simple TableView element with a few columns. I have set up a CSS document that will style each row of the table based on the status of object. In this case, a Person class has a enum with different potential status options. I have a row factory that will add / remove style classes to each row. This works just fine once I click on each row, or sort the table via clicking on the table column heads. It DOES not apply these styles until after I do this, and does not apply them on application startup and I can't figure out why. I've tried to force refresh or sort the via pre-built in code after the table has been initialized, and the row factory, but it does not seem the matter until I sort the row manually, or click on each row.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to force it to update based on the status. Any help is appreciated.

```
private ObservableList<Person> contacts;

    @FXML private BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    @FXML private TableView mainTableView;

    public void initialize() {
        contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Person person = new Person("Mark", "Pug", "555-555-5555", Person.statusOptions.NO_STATUS);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Cassy", "Garza", "222-222-2222", Person.statusOptions.AUTH_HOLD);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Adrian", "Medula", "111-111-1111", Person.statusOptions.WORKING);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Bob", "Fisher", "333-333-33330", Person.statusOptions.COMPLETE);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Toy", "Yoda", "444-444-4444", Person.statusOptions.HOLD);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Henry", "Ford", "666-666-6666", Person.statusOptions.READY);
        contacts.add(person);

        mainTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        mainTableView.setItems(contacts);

        mainTableView.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                        if (! item.getPrevStatus().equals(item.getStatus().toString())) {
                            getStyleClass().removeAll("NO_STATUS", "AUTH_HOLD", "COMPLETE", "HOLD", "READY", "WORKING");
                            getStyleClass().add(item.getStatus().toString());
                        } else {
                            if (! getStyleClass().contains(item.getStatus().toString())) {
                                getStyleClass().removeAll("NO_STATUS", "AUTH_HOLD", "COMPLETE", "HOLD", "READY", "WORKING");
                                getStyleClass().add(item.getStatus().toString());
                            }
                        }
//                        System.out.println("Style class of " + item.getFirstName() + ": " + getStyleClass());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**FOUND A SOLUTION**

```
private ObservableList<Person> contacts;

    @FXML private BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    @FXML private TableView mainTableView;

    public void initialize() {
        contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Person person = new Person("Mark", "Pug", "555-555-5555", Person.statusOptions.NO_STATUS);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Cassy", "Garza", "222-222-2222", Person.statusOptions.AUTH_HOLD);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Adrian", "Medula", "111-111-1111", Person.statusOptions.WORKING);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Bob", "Fisher", "333-333-33330", Person.statusOptions.COMPLETE);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Toy", "Yoda", "444-444-4444", Person.statusOptions.HOLD);
        contacts.add(person);
        person = new Person("Henry", "Ford", "666-666-6666", Person.statusOptions.READY);
        contacts.add(person);

        mainTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        mainTableView.setItems(contacts);

        PseudoClass working = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("WORKING");
        PseudoClass hold = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("HOLD");
        PseudoClass auth_hold = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("AUTH_HOLD");
        PseudoClass ready = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("READY");
        PseudoClass complete = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("COMPLETE");

        mainTableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
            TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
            Person selected = row.getItem();
            ChangeListener<String> changeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(working, newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("WORKING"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(hold, newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("HOLD"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(auth_hold, newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("AUTH_HOLD"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(ready, newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("READY"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(complete, newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE"));
            };

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, prevPerson, currentPerson) -> {
                if (prevPerson != null) {
                    prevPerson.statusProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                }
                if (currentPerson != null) {
                    currentPerson.statusProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(working, currentPerson.getStatus().toString().equals("WORKING"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(hold, currentPerson.getStatus().toString().equals("HOLD"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(auth_hold, currentPerson.getStatus().toString().equals("AUTH_HOLD"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(ready, currentPerson.getStatus().toString().equals("READY"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(complete, currentPerson.getStatus().toString().equals("COMPLETE"));
                } else {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(working, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(hold, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(auth_hold, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(ready, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(complete, false);
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
}
```

Although I found a solution that works, seems like its a may be a bit long solution for this problem. I'd appreciate if anyone knew how to make this more versatile. In theory I'd like a customer to be able to add or delete their own status styles in the client.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: What does the `for-loop` in the `rowfactory` do?